# Counting occurrences of values in spss

Tags: variables, loops, count, spss

I have 50 variables, named w1 to w50, and each holds a value from 1 to 20. I want to create variables showing the number of occurrences of each of these values. This is what I'd like to do, but SPSS seems to have a problem with me using #n in the COUNT command.

```
COMPUTE #n = 1 .
DO REPEAT x = num1 to num20 .
 COMPUTE x = 0 .
 COUNT x = w1 to w50 (#n) .
 COMPUTE #n = #n + 1 .
END REPEAT .
```

This is the error message I get:

Error # 4772 in column 24.  Text: #n 
On the COUNT command, the parenthesized value list is syntactically invalid. 
Execution of this command stops.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot supply a variable as the value list in the `COUNT` command. Fortunately the work around for your example is quite simple - you can use a stand in increment on the `DO REPEAT`:

```
DO REPEAT x = num1 to num20 /#i = 1 to 20.
  COUNT x = w1 to w50 (#i).
END REPEAT.
```

Full example below.

```
**********************************************.
*creating fake data.
data list free / ID.
begin data
1
2
end data.
vector w(50,F2.0).
loop #i = 1 to 50.
  compute w(#i) = TRUNC(RV.UNIFORM(1,21)).
end loop.
vector num(20,F2.0).
execute.

*making new vector.
DO REPEAT x = num1 to num20 /#i = 1 to 20.
  COUNT x = w1 to w50 (#i).
END REPEAT.
EXECUTE.
**********************************************.
```

Comment: Easier than I thought! Thanks :)